# mapStateToProps function , targeting id of the post instead of all the posts

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router-dom

I have a mapStateToProps function  where i m getting posts (all the posts) and then targeting id in render() function

show_posts.js (Component)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { fetchPost } from '../actions';

class PostsShow extends Component {
    componentDidMount() {

        const { id } = this.props.match.params ; 
        this.props.fetchPost(id);
    }


    render() {

        posts[this.props.match.params.id]; // the post i want to show

        return (
            <div>
            <h3>Title of the Post will be Here</h3>             
            </div>);
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return { posts: state.posts};

}
export default connect(mapStateToProps, {fetchPost})(PostsShow);
```

Instead of getting all the posts (imagine if there are couple of hundreds )in a `posts[this.props.match.params.id]` how can i pass a single post which is requested by the user.

index.js (Actions)

```
import axios from 'axios';

export const FETCH_POST = 'FETCH_POST';

const ROOT_URL = 'http://xxxx.abcac.com/api';
const API_KEY = '?key=xxxxxxxx';



export function fetchPost(id) {
    const request = axios.get(`${ROOT_URL}/posts/${id}${API_KEY}`);

    return {
        type: FETCH_POST,
        payload: request
    };

}
```

In my view we can targert the particular post inside mapStateToProps function i.e: state.match.params.id rather then all the posts. But dont know the right way to implement it

I m new bee to reactjs , Any help will be appreciated !
Thanks

Comment: Is posts an array or object?

Comment: @patrick its an object {}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

mapStateToProps takes a second argument typically written as `ownProps`. That is the props that have been passed to the component it is connecting to. You can read about that in the [react-redux docs](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#connectmapstatetoprops-mapdispatchtoprops-mergeprops-options)

Here's how I would implement what you're asking for:

```
function mapStateToProps(state, ownProps) {
    const postId = ownProps.match.params.id;
    const post = state.posts[postId];

    return { 
        post 
    };
}
```

Comment: I'd only add that using arrow functions for mapStateToProps() makes code a bit easier to read:

`const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({ post: state.posts[ownProps.match.params.id] });`

Comment: agreed @the_ghost but I elected not to use that since the original question was using ES5 syntax.

Answer (score 1):

How to return a single post:

```
function mapStateToProps({ posts }, ownProps) {
    return { post: posts[ownProps.match.params.id]};
}
```